# get date time from a reliable external source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datetime

I want to get DateTime from an external reliable source. I know I can get it via DateTime.Now() Method, but that can be fooled easily by changing the Systems Date and Time. Is there a way around? It is a windows form app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Network Time Server Client class.
In short, you ask one of the numerous Time Server on Internet the date and time to set your internal PC clock using the [NTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

If you search for NTP Client you will find numerous examples.

[This is the first](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C) that came out from a Bing Search

Quoting:

> ```
> The Network Time Protocol (NTP) and its simplified form (SNTP) are widely used to 
> synchronize network resources, due to their simplicity and effectiveness.
> ```

Of course, as everything installed on a client PC, also this could be hacked faking the address of the time server and returning a different value. But this will require more work from the hacker than simply resetting the PC clock.

Answer (score 0):

While you might implement a [Network Time Protocol](http://www.ntp.org/) client in your app and request the current time over the net or request something from some http server and use the time from `Date` response header, this also may be fooled (the one may intercept the traffic and send you responses on behalf of the time server you will be connecting or tweak http response).

Though, the easiest is to get response from some http server.